# Argument type error

Tags: c, types, arguments, structure, scanf

The following code shows that
format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 11 has type 'int' 
format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 12 has type 'int'
I don't see any mistakes in variable types.

```
typedef struct{

        char country[20];
        char town[20];
    }location;
    typedef struct{
        int birthday_day;
        int birthday_month;
        int birthday_year;
    } birthday;
    typedef struct{
        char university;
        char department;
        int year_of_graduation;
    }education;
    typedef struct{
        int id;
        char name[20];
        char surname[20];
        location place;
        birthday birth;
    education school;
        int quantity_of_friends;
        int quantity_of_likes;
        int quantity_of_posts;
    }user;

user usser[100];
int i;

for (i=0;i<100;i++){
fscanf(input,"%i %s %s %s %s %i %i %i %s %s %i %i %i %i ", &usser[i].id, usser[i].name,usser[i].surname, usser[i].place.country,usser[i].place.town, &usser[i].birth.birthday_day,&usser[i].birth.birthday_month, &usser[i].birth.birthday_year, usser[i].school.university, usser[i].school.department,&usser[i].school.year_of_graduation,    &usser[i].quantity_of_friends,&usser[i].quantity_of_likes, &usser[i].quantity_of_posts);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you declared only character variables

```
    char university;
    char department;
```

but you expect string from that which cause warning.

So might be like

```
    char university[100];
    char department[100];
```

Comment: right. damn. somehow I missed the condition that the name of the uni should be an array. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this

```
typedef struct{
    char university;
    char department;
    int year_of_graduation;
}education;
```

`university` and `department` should be char array, not only char.

Answer (score 0):

In education struct, `university` and `department` just two single chars, you need to define them as arrays

```
    char university[SIZE];
    char department[SIZE];
```